# Change list of values dynamically with a click

Tags: entities, nodes

I realize my request is a bit complex, I hope someone can answer.

I have a drupal 7 clean installation. I have a node type called `Whole` and another one called `Piece`. A `Whole` contains one to many `Piece`: I used the Entity module (with Entity reference) to link entities. The `Piece` node has a boolean field called `selected`.

When a user views a `Whole` node he can see all the `Piece` elements linked to it.

I need to allow an unlogged user to set the `selected` field of the `piece` node to `true` without leaving the `Whole` node page. I also need to keep track of the selected `Piece` elements (maybe in a session variable?). In the end I need to list all the `Pieces` altered in the session to compose a mail. When the mail is sent the session is cleared.

Is there a module that allows in place edit of node attributes?? I have installed and tried `Editable Views`, but it doesn't work. Maybe there is a conflict with my drupal version (7.14) which unfortunately I can't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to let anon visitors edit nodes to achieve this, and I wouldn't recommend it. It presents a security issue, and would store the "selected" status as a property of the node (for all visitors).

Rather, you can store the selected nodes in a session or a cookie, using a standalone drupal form. Create a form, like so:

```
function YOURMODULE_node_store_form($form, &$form_state, $nid) {
  $form_state['nid'] = $nid;
  $dv = (isset($_SESSION['node_store'] && in_array($nid, $_SESSION['node_store']) ? 1 : NULL;
  $form['selected'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => 'Include this page in email.',
    '#default_value' => $dv,
  );
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
  );
  return $form;
}

function YOURMODULE_node_store_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  if($form_state['values']['selected'] && $form_state['nid']) {
    $_SESSION['node_store'][] = $form_state['nid'];
    drupal_set_message('The page will be included in the email.');
  }
}
```

In the template file for the Piece content type, add the form to the teaser display, like so:

```
<?php print render(drupal_get_form(MYMODULE_node_store_form, $node->nid);) ?>
```

To include the stored nodes in the mail, you can retrieve them from the $_SESSION['node_store'] array. Once the email has been sent, you should probably clear the $_SESSION['node_store'] array.

If you DO have to store it to the node, use the node_save function in your submit handler, instead:

```
function YOURMODULE_node_store_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  if($form_state['values']['selected'] && $node = node_load($form_state['nid'])) {
    $node->field_selected[$node->language][0]['value'] = 1;
    node_save($node);
    $_SESSION['node_store'][] = $node->nid;
    drupal_set_message('The page will be included in the email.');
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try your suggestion for sure, but I need users to edit permanently the field's value. Maybe it is safer to create a single account for all users to avoid unallowed accesses.

Comment: ok, then I'm not sure I understand. Why do they need to permanently edit it?

Comment: This should work like _a sort_ of ecommerce chart, when a person gets a piece it's sold and can't be "bought" by another person.

Comment: ok, I get it. :) I've updated the answer.

Comment: Tested, two small mistakes in code but it's ok (+1) I still need to figure out how to make it work in a view, the form is created correctly but it returns an error on submission. Many thanks meanwhile :)

Comment: You can use the "selected" field in a view, but the session variable won't be available.  To send the email, I'd recommend using hook_mail and hook_mail_send.

Comment: Marked as correct as I didn't mention views in my question, thanks! Now I need to figure out how to handle things with views

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15490/discussion-between-olyn-and-gabber).